# Making background image reveal bottom first when scrolling?

Tags: html, css

I am attempting to make a feature like https://www.artyofficial.com/ has.

When scrolling down, the bottom of the second image will appear while the first image starts to get cut away. How is something like this achievable with CSS? I would post a style sheet but unfortunately I don't even know where to begin here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is the [parallax scrolling effect](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp)

The most important property is the `background-attachment: fixed;` here.

I made you a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6f2dqd0g/8/) easy as possible, take a look at it.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by looking at the [background-attachment](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_background-attachment.asp) property, it has a value of:

`fixed    The background is fixed with regard to the viewport`

Answer (score 1):

It is called as parallax effect. You can refer to link: [Parallax Effect](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_parallax.asp)

```
<style>
.parallax { 
    /* The image used */
    background-image: url("img_parallax.jpg");

    /* Set a specific height */
    height: 500px; 

    /* Create the parallax scrolling effect */
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-position: center;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;
}
</style>

<!-- Container element -->
<div class="parallax"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You just need to give all your such consecutive div's `background-attachment: fixed`. Check the example below:

```css
.panels{
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center center;
}

.panels:nth-child(1){background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/');}

.panels:nth-child(2){background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nightlife/');}

.panels:nth-child(3){background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/cats/');}

.panels:nth-child(4){background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/food/');}

.panels:nth-child(5){background-image: url('http://lorempixel.com/400/200/nature/');}


/* this is for hiding stackoverflow console */
.as-console-wrapper{ display: none !important; }
```

```html
<div class="panels"></div>
<div class="panels"></div>
<div class="panels"></div>
<div class="panels"></div>
<div class="panels"></div>
```